# Matching email addresses with regex

Tags: regex

I would like to match all of the following formats.

It is important that there is only 1 `+` or none in the case of `support@domain.tld`.
Like so:

```
support@domain.tld
842dcaef90ea4ff6b995f8614ce620e8+support@domain.tld
2223-842dcaef90ea4ff6b995f8614ce620e8+support@domain.tld
33333-2223-842dcaef90ea4ff6b995f8614ce620e8+support@domain.tld
```

But should not match the extended email if there is no plus symbol:

```
842dcaef90ea4ff6b995f8614ce620e8-support@domain.tld
2223-842dcaef90ea4ff6b995f8614ce620e8-support@domain.tld
33333-2223-842dcaef90ea4ff6b995f8614ce620e8-support@domain.tld
```

I have this, but it's not working as wanted.

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+?\+support@domain.tld$
```

Comment: You should set the 'multiline' option, then it will match all with a plus sign.

Comment: Your regex works as you want: See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/UUY3BGtlcv8UDK).

Comment: @Bohemian It doesn't match just `support@domain.tld`.

Comment: My apologies. Reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the leading part optional:

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+?\+)?support@domain.tld$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/1Y0YXhAvlyrc0a).